# Firefox remote debug "unexpected error" on Windows 8

Tags: android, debugging, firefox, adb

I need debug a web application in Firefox for "Android". I am trying to connect the device to desktop Firefox, but always got the error "unexpected error".

I have performed all steps of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Firefox_for_Android

1. I installed the Android SDK Tools and Platforms, and the device is correctly detected with the adb command.
2. I enabled remote debugging on desktop Firefox and Firefox for Android
3. I enabled remote USB debugging on the device.
4. The device is connected to the original cable to my PC.
5. I run the command adb forward tcp: 6000 tcp: 6000 on the command line without problems.
6. Finally, the developer desktop Firefox menu, I choose the connect option. Page appears to connect to localhost: 6000, and clicking on the "connect" button, the error "unexpected error" appears.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Found the solution!**

Instead of typing:

```
adb forward tcp:6000 tcp:6000
```

type in the following:

```
adb forward tcp:6000 localfilesystem:/data/data/org.mozilla.firefox/firefox-debugger-socket
```

The first command is for firefox 34, for latter versions, you need the second.

Also, according to the docs:

> For Firefox for Android builds in other channels, the
>   org.mozilla.firefox part should be changed to:
>
> - org.mozilla.firefox_beta for Beta
> - org.mozilla.fennec_aurora for Aurora
> - org.mozilla.fennec for Nightly

Comment: None of the solution you provided worked. Any other reasons that could be??

Comment: Is your 6000 port unoccupied?