# Remote debugging of Firefox apps, now that Xulrunner is removed?

Tags: debugging, firefox, xulrunner

I'm trying to debug https://github.com/prikhi/pencil ; the [./docs/source/developers/index.rst](https://github.com/prikhi/pencil/blob/develop/docs/source/developers/index.rst) file notes, that after the DEBUG build, one runs the application with:

```
# If you've got XULRunner:
xulrunner Outputs/Linux/application.ini -console -jsconsole -purgecaches
# If you only have Firefox installed:
firefox --app Outputs/Linux/application.ini -console -jsconsole -purgecaches
```

It also notes:

> Setting `DEBUG` will cause also Pencil to start a remote debugging server on
>   port `6000`. This lets you use Firefox's DOM Inspector to debug Pencil - **but
>   only when you run Pencil using `xulrunner`**. You can connect Firefox to the
>   debugging server by going to `Firefox -> Tools -> Web Developer ->
>   Connect...`. You may need to enable Remote Debugging under Firefox's `Web
>   Developer Tools` Settings(`Ctrl-Shift-I` then click the gear icon in the
>   upper-right).

The problem is that the current Firefox is 42, and since this version, `xulrunner` is not built nor packaged anymore:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/125980/how-do-i-install-xulrunner
- [How to download xulrunner sdk for Firefox beta (Firefox 42) • mozillaZine Forums](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=2967815)

http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/xulrunner/nightly/latest-mozilla-aurora/Deprecation_notice.txt

> We no longer produce runtimes. Further information see 'XULRunner future and ownership' at
>   https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla.dev.platform/_rFMunG2Bgw/C-4PcHj9IgAJ

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mozilla.dev.platform/_rFMunG2Bgw/C-4PcHj9IgAJ

> The Mozilla project no longer sees XULRunner as a priority project.  ...
>   ... we are turning off automated
>   XULRunner builds and so XULRunner will probably quickly cease to work. ...
>   ... remove the XULRunner code from the mozilla-central repository ...

So, after enabling remote debugging in Firefox 42, and building Pencil in DEBUG build, running pencil with:

```
firefox --app /path/to/pencil/build/Outputs/Linux/application.ini -console -jsconsole -purgecaches
```

Then from another instance of Firefox, I try Tools/Web Developer/Connect ... - tried both 127.0.0.1 and localhost at port 6000, I get the prompt (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Remote_Debugging/Debugging_Firefox_Desktop), but after I say OK, I get nothing listed:

[image: firefox.png]

So, seemingly `xulrunner` is indeed required to debug XUL apps remotely via Firefox.

But how can I remote-debug this application, now that `xulrunner` has been removed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firefox remote debug "unexpected error" on Windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29513692/firefox-remote-debug-unexpected-error-on-windows-8)